# How can I assert calls that accept sequence arguments with Python Mock?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am processing a sequence of user-defined objects. It looks similar to the following:

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

The method I am currently testing has functionality similar to the following:

```
def my_function(things):
    x_calc = calculate_something(t.x for t in things)
    y_calc = calculate_something(t.y for t in things)
    return x_calc / y_calc
```

The problem I am facing is testing the calls to `calculate_something`. I want to assert that these calls happened, something like so:

```
calculateSomethingMock.assert_any_call(the_sequence)
```

I don't care about the order of the sequence passed into `calculate_something`, but I do care that the elements are all present. I could wrap the generator function in a call to `set`, but I don't feel like my test should be dictating what type of sequence is passed into `calculate_something`. I should be able to pass it any kind of sequence. I could alternatively create a method that generates the sequence instead of using generator syntax and mock that method, but that seems like overkill.

How can I best structure this assertion, or is my trouble testing here an indication of poorly structured code?

I am using Python 2.7.3 with Mock 1.0.1.

(For anyone who feels compelled to comment on it, I'm aware I'm doing test last and that this isn't considered the greatest practice.)

Edit:

After watch [this marvelous talk entitled "Why You Don't Get Mock Objects by Gregory Moeck"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9FOchgTtLM), I have reconsidered whether I should even be mocking the `calculate_something` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't touched the code I was originally working with for a good while, but I've been reconsidering my approach to testing in general. I've been trying to be more careful about what I do and don't mock. I recently realized that I was unconsciously starting to following this rule of thumb: mock something if it makes my test shorter and simpler and leave it alone if it makes the test more complicated. Simple input/output testing suffices in the case of this method. There are no external dependencies like a database or files. So in short, I think the answer to my question is, "I shouldn't mock `calculate_something`." Doing so makes my test harder to read and maintain.

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the Mock documentation, there is a [call_args_list](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.call_args_list) that will do what you want.

So you will Mock out `calculate_something` on your test.

```
calculate_something = Mock(return_value=None)
```

After you `my_function` has finished you can check the arguments passed by doing:

```
calculate_something.call_args_list
```

which will return a list of all the calls made to it (with the corresponding elements passed).

*Edit*:

(Sorry it took me so long, I had to install Python3.3 on my machine)

**mymodule.py**

```
class Thing:
    ...
def calculate_something:
    ...

def my_function(things):
    # Create the list outside in order to avoid a generator object
    # from being passed to the Mock object.

    xs = [t.x for t in things]
    x_calc = calculate_something(xs)

    ys = [t.y for t in things]
    y_calc = calculate_something(ys)
    return True
```

**test_file.py**

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, call
import mymodule



class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):

    # You can patch calculate_something here or
    # do so inside the test body with 
    # mymodule.calcualte_something = Mock()
    @patch('mymodule.calculate_something')
    def test_mock(self, mock_calculate):

        things = [mymodule.Thing(3, 4), mymodule.Thing(7, 8)]

        mymodule.my_function(things)

        # call_args_list returns [call([3, 7]), call([4, 8])]
        callresult = mock_calculate.call_args_list


        # Create our own call() objects to compare against
        xargs = call([3, 7])
        yargs = call([4, 8])

        self.assertEqual(callresult, [xargs, yargs])

        # or
        # we can extract the call() info
        # http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/helpers.html#mock.call.call_list
        xargs, _ = callresult[0]
        yargs, _ = callresult[1]

        xexpected = [3, 7]
        yexpected = [4, 8]

        self.assertEqual(xargs[0], xexpected)
        self.assertEqual(yargs[0], yexpected)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: I try to avoid digging into that list, but I suppose it might be the only way. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Thanks. This test relies on the method preserving order, and it also relies on the method passing in a list. I'm not very keen on the test relying on order. If I decide to change to some other data structure for the argument passed into `calculate_something`, do I want the test to fail? Or conversely, if I change the test to check the call for a different data type, do I want to have to modify the method to make it pass again?

Comment: Yes, but remember this is an example.

You can pass `calculate_something` any other data structure, just update the test to reflect that (By changing the expected values). You want the test to pass after all. 

You already saw how to get the arguments passed to `calculate_something` using `call_args_list`. After that, it's just a matter of comparing the data structured passed with what you are expecting.